Is, "The sea is always right," a concept from Tolkien's legendarium?
Is the Númenorean saying, "The sea is always right," in the TV series The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power based on a concept from Tolkien's legendarium, or was this idea created for the TV series?
In the TV series, this phrase appears to be a significant motto for the Númenoreans. In Season 1, Episode 3, Elendil explains to Míriel that he brought Galadriel to Númenor because "the sea put her in [his] path," adding, "The sea is always right." We also hear Isildur and other Sea Guard cadets echo this phrase as a sort of motto.
Later, in Season 2, Episode 6, Elendil faces a "Trial by Abyss" for refusing to bow to Ar-Pharazôn. When Míriel urges him to submit, Elendil stands firm, saying, "If it is the will of the Valar that my life be spared, then it will be," and again repeats, "The sea is always right."
This recurring phrase seems to imply that events at sea are viewed as the will of the Valar and are therefore "always right."
Given its prominence in the show, I'm curious if the Tolkien texts contain a similar concept or saying about the sea and its connection to divine will, or if this idea was created for the TV series.

No.  Just more Amazon nonsense.

Possibly a confused reference to Ulmo, the Vala who is lord of the waters, and/or his vassal Ossë, who were both friendly to the Elves and intervened several times? Again, the makers of RoP have no rights to these characters so cannot mention them by name.

No one in Tolkien's works would say anything so dumb and awkward.

"If it is the will of the Valar that my life be spared" also misrepresents how the Faithful would have understood the Valar. They were not gods that controlled the fate and destiny of men (though they, or at least Mandos, might know something more about said fates than the men themselves).

A search of my digital copies of Tolkien's works (including the published fiction and the History of Middle-earth, although I have not actually read all of the latter straight through) shows no evidence of anything like this sentiment ever expressed in a Númenorean context.  (I tried a bunch of variations on the search terms.)
On the other hand, there are plenty of references to the Númenoreans as great sailors—which is hardly surprising.  The royal house of Elros Tar-Minyatur (and by the time of the Akallabêth, all the folk of Westernese) were descended from the greatest of all mariners, Eärendil.  Even the ents were said to have heard news of when the Númenorean sea kings' great ships returned to Middle-earth.

This answer seems to ignore Ulmo, and the role Ulmo played in the events of the First Age which lead indirectly to the creation of Númenor (which Ulmo had a direct hand in). Given that, until the Númenorean power holders rebelled against Aman, they deeply revered the  Valar. Is it such a surprise that a Númenorean sailor would hold the sea in holy reverence?

Elrond was the immediate son of Eärendil, and not exactly a mariner. Tar-Meneldur (Eärendil's great-great-great-grandson) actively disapproved of his son Aldarion's passion for seafaring. There were many great Númenorean mariners, but it was hardly a defining trait of the nation or its rulers (both of which were more interested in the power to be exerted over and riches extracted from Middle-Earth, sailing being a means to an end).
